# Narrow paragraph block aligned to left of "wrapper"

Tags: css, block-editor, theme.json, full-site-editing

I'm using the full-site-editing feature with

```
  "layout":{
     "contentSize":"1264px",
     "wideSize":"1264px"
  }
```

set in **theme.json**. Now when I create a paragraph block, I get:
[image]

I need it 830px wide (more readable), but aligned to left. But when I set `max-width:830px`, it gets centered by `auto` margins and escapes the 1264px "wrapper":
[image]

What is the cleanest way to achieve this

- without forcing admins to create group blocks around paragraph blocks
- so that it gets applied in the editor too

Comment: have you tried opening the post template these blocks appear in and changing the alignment of the parent block outside of the post content? The post content itself is wrapped in blocks at a higher level if you go into the site editor

Comment: Changing their alignment in what way? Not sure it helps, the `entry-content` container is full-width so you can have full width blocks in the design too, so if you force its children to go left, it's left of the full-width and not of the 1264 content size.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my solution so far, though it doesn't seem ideal to me. Also the `.entry-content` parent doesn't get applied in the editor.

```
/* trick to have root paragraphs left-aligned "in the central wrapper" without extra dom */
.entry-content > p{
    padding-right:calc(1264px - 830px);
    max-width:1264px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1300px){
    .entry-content > p{
        padding-right:calc(100% - 830px);
    }
}
```